# Typescript d.ts files in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, type-declaration

While migrating our Typescript solution from using Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017, we have encountered a problem where we have a d.ts file in our root directory (not in node_modules/@types) where we declare some vars, and an ambient module declaration.

This was automatically referenced in 2015, but now in 2017 it is not automatically referenced and throws errors in other files regarding implicit any returning from the function declared in the ambient type declaration file. We don't reference the d.ts file anywhere through imports etc, ie. it is global.

For reference, we are not using the new TS language service, and we do not allow implicit any in our TS files.

Building the solution via command line with Typescript (the version installed from package.json) does not output any errors.

If we open the d.ts file in Visual Studio 2017, it then picks it up and we don't have the error.

We have tried using the typeRoots tsconfig.json property but it doesn't seem to work.

So our observations:

1. It seems Visual Studio 2017 only looks for type definitions in
   'node_modules/@types.
2. Once the file has been opened, the d.ts
   file is referenced correctly

If these are true, how does one use their own custom definition files without adding them as npm modules? Surely this isn't the standard way.

Comment: Please add your `tsconfig.json` file to the question.